# StructureMap on Xamarin: System.Reflection.TypeExtensions not found

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection

It seems like I cannot use StructureMap:

```
[Mono] The class System.Reflection.TypeExtensions could not be loaded, used in System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

I added System.Reflection.TypeExtensions :

```
<package id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

I can see that DLL in references. I still get the same error.

Any hints?

I need StructureMap because I couldn't pass constructor parameters when I used SimpleInjector. In StrcutureMap it's easy:

```
_container.With(offer).GetInstance<OfferDetailsViewModel>(); // "offer" will be passed to the ctor of OfferDetailsViewModel
```

Comment: It appears no one has answered this question yet. Did you figure it out or did you move on to AutoFac or something like that?

Comment: @ColinPear no, I stuck with SimpleInjector.

Comment: Are you using a Portable Class Library (PCL)? I wonder if its just not part of the template.

Comment: @ColinPear I think at that time, I had already switched to shared projects instead of PCL. I don't remember now tbh